# Lynx cannot render "Button" tag

Tags: android, html, syntax-highlighting

I am checking a tutorial with [Lnyx](http://www.delorie.com/web/lynxview.html) and I bumped into a strange problem.

I have written a couple of tutorials for myself, all have xml and java codes copied from Eclipse. My first problem is that Lnyx has a problem with xml code, for example it can see

```
 android:id="@+id/btn_oneshot"
```

but it cannot see

```
&lt;Button android:id="@+id/btn_oneshot"
```

meaning whole blocks are invisible, like

```
   &lt;Button android:id="@+id/btn_oneshot"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="Start One Shot Alarm" />
```

I need to use "& lt;" instead of "<" because I am using a SyntaxHighlighter. If I used "<" (but I can't)

Lynx would display

```
 [BUTTON] main.xml:
```

It looks like this is the reason that most of my page code is displayed in huge gray boxes by Lynx, instead of simple text. I checked some of my tutorials and it turned out that those who don't have a "& lt;Button" in xml are working fine, while those who has "& lt;Button" in xml aren't, meaning I can have a  & lt;RatingBar or  & lt;TextView in the code without any problems.

This is the print screen of Lnyx showing NO xml:

[image]

When I change the "& lt;Button" in XML code to "& lt;Buttons", the xml is still invisible, but the gray block is now missing:

[image]

**As a conclusion:**

1) The xml code is never visible

2) The rest of the code is in gray boxes (with no selectable text) when I am using "& lt;Button" in any xml code.

I am not sure about this, but as far as I know, what Lynx cannot see the search spiders cannot see, and this goes for the gray blocks as well. Or Lynx renders Button badly and the content is still visible for spiders. What do you think?

I checked in Chrome, IE9 and Firefox 14.0.1

Comment: i'm not sure what your attempting to accomplish. lynx is a web browser and your code is for an android application.

Comment: Isn't Lynx used to display the html page as the search spiders see it?